# Why doesn't >> prepend strings in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

In ruby, you can append strings using `<<`:

```
>> "Hello" << "World"
=> "HelloWorld"
```

So why can't you prepend them using `>>`?

```
>> "Hello" >> "World"
NoMethodError: undefined method `>>' for "Hello":String
```

I realise `String` doesn't have the `>>` method defined, but what's the reasoning behind that?

Comment: Whose method would it be? `Hello`'s or `World`'s?

Comment: i cant think of any reason why you can't do it, but wouldn't the functionality of the method be identical?  you might think of it as prepending, but ruby just sees 2 strings and sticks the string on the right of the equation to the end of the string on the left.

Comment: I would assume because doing that is uncommon, and the commonly known meaning for `>>` is "right-shift-bits", so it avoids confusion; and because it is easy to write your own.

Comment: one question: using a simple "+" to build a new string ("Hello" + "World") is acceptable or you really need an inplace operation? if so, why?

Comment: @Zabba - `<<` is also commonly known as left-shift, so I'm not sure that logic holds.

Comment: @Mladen: It would be on Hello.

Comment: @Simon: And what would you expect as a result? Because it would really be counter-intuitive for result to be `'WordHello'`, as the direction of the "arrows" could only suggest "prepend `Hello` to `World`".

Comment: @Mladen I'd expect 'WorldHello' because I'd expect `x >> y` to return the same as `y << x`.  But your intuition makes sense too.  Perhaps that's the answer - because it would have to be counter-intuitive, one way or the other.

Answer (score 26):

Ruby 1.9.3 added a String#prepend method.

The proposal about adding prepend[1] also included the ">>" method, and there's some discussion on the thread about that implementation [2]:

> Matz says: " >> is interesting notation did not think about it."
>
> sorya says: "This patch is out it had been discussed several times towards the IRC"

However at the end of the thread, the conclusion was to accept String#prepend, and that "other proposals including String # >> are pending."

I couldn't find any other discussion about it though... anyone else?

Personally, I like it, and it's trivial to add:

```rb
class String
  def >> (s)
    s.prepend(self)
  end
end
```

The result:

```
>> "Hello" >> "World"
=> "HelloWorld"
```

[1] http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/3675

[2] http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=ja&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fbugs.ruby-lang.org%2Fissues%2F3675

Comment: This does the exact same thing as `<<` then, only it isn't natively optimized. If you're saying `>>` is an alias for `prepend`, it should actually prepend the argument to the object. You would be better off just doing `class String; alias :>> :<<; end` than using the native `prepend` method if what you really mean is that you want `:>>` to join in the order that the strings appear in source.

Comment: @coreyward, that's not true. Everyone has been working with String literals and the point gets a little obscured. If you aliasing >> to <<, there's obviously no prepending. The return value of the operation is the same, but if we are working with variables we get the opposite of what we want. If we have a = "Hello" and b = "World", a >> b and a << b mean something different.

Comment: @AnthonyDeSimone I think your comment could be more clear, but the point about string literals versus variables is valid. Still, I doubt that we will see this in Ruby/ActiveSupport anytime soon as it violates what you expect to happen simply to scratch a very human itch of wanting things to balance out (i.e. wanting a `>>` to complement our `<<`).

Comment: @coreyward, you're right. What I meant to point out was in one case we're permanently modifying a, and in the other case we're permanently modifying b.

Answer (score 20):

Ruby's syntax wouldn't allow a method like `>>` to be implemented the way you expect.

`<<` in `"Hello" << "World"` is equivalent to the following:

`"Hello".<<("World")`

If you wanted to create a prepend method `>>`, I would expect "Hello" in `"Hello" >> "World"` to be the argument to the string `"World"`:

`("Hello")>>."World"` which isn't valid Ruby syntax.

If "World" was an argument to "Hello", then you would just be appending a string like fl00r demonstrated. Aliasing `>>` to mean the same as `<<` would cause confusion.

This is why you have the `insert` method instead. If you want to insert "Hello" in front of "World" you would call insert on "World":

`"World".insert(0, "Hello ")`

The takeaway here is to keep in mind that `<<` is a method call just like a string method such as `length`, so you have to keep the ordering similar to regular method calls.

Comment: Why would you expect that?  Why wouldn't it be "Hello".>>("World")?

Comment: To me part of the purpose of using a shorthand like `<<` is to denote that the string is being "pushed" onto another string. Effectively it's an arrow saying "this string is added to this other string". If you think about it in that perspective, using `>>` would read 'add "Hello" to "World"'. Then it would make sense to say that "World" is the object you're adding "Hello" to, which syntactically doesn't make sense now (argument on left of operator).

Comment: Makes sense.  Hadn't occurred to me before, and as I said to Mladen, it might be that the two contradictory interpretations are the reason it hasn't been done.

Comment: And if it's `"Hello".>>("World")`, then all you've done is redefine `<<`. How is `"Hello".>>("World")` which would produce "HelloWorld", any different than `"Hello".<<("World")` (also produces "HelloWorld")? Either way you'd be manipulating the "Hello" string in this case, never "World", because like I mentioned previously, "World" is the argument, not the object acted upon with that syntax.

Comment: @Simon - Sorry didn't get your newest comment until just now, hopefully my new comments help shed more light.

Comment: @McStretch yeah - It doesn't make sense for it to return "HelloWorld" if it's a method on "Hello"; I had assumed it would return "WorldHello", so that "Hello" >> "World" was the same as "World" << "Hello".

Comment: @Simon - yeah, I was aiming for the same logic as Mladen's more recent comments, sorry if my explanation didn't come across as clear.

Comment: In Ruby 1.9.3 there is `"world".prepend("Hello ")`.

Comment: The reason they are different is that `String#<<` doesn't just return a value, it modifies the string you call it on. With `a << b`, `a` now contains its previous contents followed by the contents of `b`. With `a >> b` (if it existed), it would modify `b` instead to now contain its previous contents preceded by `a`. Also, the "argument ordering" reasoning doesn't make sense. When you call a method on an object and pass it an argument, the method has references to both. There's no reason you'd need them to be in a particular arrangement to achieve this functionality, as Patrick demonstrates.

Answer (score 6):

Ruby always asigns value from the right to the left.

But you can implement it by yourself

```
class String
  def >>(s)
    s << self
  end
end

"Hello" >> "world"
#=> "worldHello"
```

Comment: He said "prepend", so I assume the expected output would still be "HelloWorld".

Comment: so what's the difference between your `>>` above and existing `String#<<`?

Comment: @Michael - appending gives "HelloWorld", so I'd expect prepending to give "WorldHello"

Comment: @Mladen Jablanović, Here is no difference :) But @Simon asked why there is no `>>` method with the same functionality as `<<` I told that it is because assigment direction and that he can extend `String` class. I don't know why he needs it :)

Comment: return my first answer back with `worldHello`

Comment: Well, that's the problem. It's not natural for a Ruby method to mutate an argument rather than object it's called on. I guess that's the reason `String#>>` doesn't exist. :)

Comment: @Mladen Jablanović, actually we can return `self = s + self` so argument won't be changed

Comment: Not quite (as `self` can't be assigned to), but yes, you could do `insert(0, s)`. But anyway, that particular `>>` would be counter-intuitive, as everyone expects `'Hello' >> 'World'` to result in `'HelloWorld'`, isn't it?

Comment: Only topic author wants "WorldHello" :D

Comment: In other words, this answer suggests that the direction of the "arrow" expressed by `<<` is expressing the direction of affection (the argument on the right affects the receiver on the left), and whether that happens to be concatenation on the left end (as it is) or on the right end is an independent thing. I think this answer is reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I would do this, but if someone forced me to:

```
class String
  def prepend(string)
    insert(0, string)
  end
end
```

I don't think `>>` is a good idea—the reason `<<` is nice is because it looks like what's going to happen. `>>` looks like it would have the same result as `<<` to me, except that the calling object is being prepended onto the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good question, and the issue is more general than just the problem with the notation `<<` as suggested in McStretch's answer because there is a same situation with the methods given in an alphabet. Namely, there is `String#concat`, which **appends** an argument string to `self`, but there is no method that **prepends** an argument string.

Comment: There is a method that prepends an argument string, it's called `String#insert`.

Comment: No, it doesn't do that. You have to obligatorily give `0` as the first argument to make it work as prepend.

Comment: Yeah I agree, but to say that there is no method that **prepends** is still wrong IMHO. Insert prepends, it just doesn't have a nice shortcut.

Comment: The point of the original question was that there is not opposite counterpart to `<<` (although you can manage to do it in a different way). I wrote that there is no counterpart to `concat` either. You can't consider 'insert' as the counterpart that pairs with `concat`. They have different syntax. You can let `insert` work like prepend as a special case, but `insert` itself is not prepend.

Comment: And as Patrick Smith points out, as of 1.9.3, there is indeed a prepend method.